# Meaning of SIS in accelerators

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, accelerator-physics

With reference to accelerator facilities, the term "SIS" is often used. e.g. SIS-100, SIS-300 etc.

What does SIS stand for, in this context?

(The last S is probably for Synchrotron)

Google appears to be taking for granted everybody knows.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: I have two answers that are both helpful. I upvoted both, but I have no idea which one to accept over the other. :(

Comment: But thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 1):

SIS-100/ SIS-300 is an accelerator under construction for FAIR (Facility for Antiproton and Ion Research) in Darmstadt, Germany.

see - http://cern.ch/AccelConf/e08/papers/mopc100.pdf

I believe, but am not sure, that the -100 and -300 refers to the magnetic rigidity (i.e. Magnetic field * bending radius) of the accelerators, which determines the maximum energy particles they can handle. SIS-300 will be an upgrade to SIS-100

As John Rennie says, SIS itself stands for SchwerIonenSynchrotron, or heavy ion synchrotron.

Comment: Very helpful. Let me first try to make sense of the rigidity thing. If I don't get it, I'll ask you why it is so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The SIS accelerators are heavy ion accelerators, and the German for heavy ion accelerator is
SchwerIonenSynchrotron (my capitalisation), hence the abbreviation SIS. There is more info [in this article](http://cerncourier.com/cws/article/cern/56209).

Comment: Very helpful. It also takes care of my next question, why would that be called SIS. Thank you.